# How can I get a village to stop chasing my giants?

Tags: reus

In an attempt to build a Bank then Multinational in *Reus*, I accidentally-on-purpose turbocharged a village's economy and mismanaged Danger for a few minutes, leading to the villagers getting exceedingly greedy.  Now they seem to love the Rock Giant and do laps to try to feather him.

Can I directly damage/destroy the mob chasing me to thwart them or otherwise discourage the horde?

Answer (score 4):

You can destroy the mob with the Swamp Giant's moss ball attack, or the rock giant's earthquaking attack. Destroying their village will also destroy the mob, if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you also can cast ocean on the mob. Doing so will get them drown and a message will appear: "The village is humiliated" or something like this. Doing so will not only destroy mob but also will reset the village's greed counter to 0.